JavaCV frame reading not working on Raspberry Pi
i am currently developing an application to scan QR codes with Java and JavaCV.
On my mac, it works just fine. Opens the camera, reads the frames and detects + decodes the QR code.
When i run the code on my Raspberry Pi, the application starts but no frames are read.
The connected camera itself is working, i already took a sample picture with libcamera-still. When i run vcgencmd get_camera it outputs supported=0 detected=0, libcamera interfaces=0. What's the issue? Can anybody help?
I use Spring Boot (v 3.3.1) with Maven. My Raspberry is a model 4B.

I got it resolved. For anybody curious how i managed to get this up and running: I changed the dtoverlay to correct version for my camera and setup a loopback device that delivers the frames to a dummy device which i can use in my application. Works perfectly fine.

I got it resolved. For anybody curious how i managed to get this up and running: I changed the dtoverlay to correct version for my camera and setup a loopback device that delivers the frames to a dummy device which i can use in my application. Works perfectly fine.
